# JVMTI not loaded

Tags: java, jvmti

I'm trying to use the JVMTI in order to write a little Java debugger in C++.
I read here:
http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/jvmti/
that the JVM should call an exported method defined like
`JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Agent_OnLoad(JavaVM *jvm, char *options, void *reserved)`

But I don't see this method called when I run my debugger even if I start my java target program.
Is this the correct way to start this JVMTI? Is  it supposed to be called automatically when a java program is started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The debug agent code is loaded when you supply "-agentlib" command-line argument while calling a Java program, like:

```
$java -agentlib:jvmti_debugger javaSampleClass
```

A little more recent article about it is located [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/jvm_ti/).